# Iterate efficiently on large OneToMany – ManyToOne associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `User` and `Period`, they have a ManyToMany association: a user belongs to many periods, and a period has multiple users. This association uses a `UserPeriod` entity.

```
class Period
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserPeriod", mappedBy="period")
     */
    private $users;
}

class UserPeriod
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="periods")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Period", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $period;
}

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserPeriod", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $periods;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is getting a list of all users from a defined period. Since there is a lot of users, I can't load them all in memory and must iterate on them (batch processing). Here is what I tried:

```
public function getUsersOfQuery($period)
{
    return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('u')
                ->from('SGLotteryUserBundle:LotteryUser', 'u')
                ->innerJoin('u.periods', 'p')
                ->where('p.period = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $period->id())
                ->getQuery();
}

$it = $repo->getUsersOfQuery($period)->iterate();
```

But, this exception is raised:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                           
Iterate with fetch join in class UserPeriod using association user not allowed.
```

I cannot use native queries since `User` uses table inheritance.

Comment: You could use setMaxResults() to limit the number of rows and use pagination principle to retrieve all your users. I assume that you won't display hundred of users details on the same view.

Comment: @sdespont This isn't for display, I need to do some process on all of them.

Comment: In fact, you cannot iterate with queries that fetch-join a collection-valued association. https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results

Comment: @sdespont I do understand your point, and I already knew that actually: since a join may lead to multiple rows per root entity, iterating may not work. But, in my case, all the joins are "1:1", so the number of rows matches the number of entities.

Answer (score 10):

[Github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5868)

> This happens when using either MANY_TO_MANY or ONE_TO_MANY join in
>   your query then you cannot iterate over it because it is potentially
>   possible that the same entity could be in multiple rows.
>
> If you add a distinct to your query then all will work as it will
>   guarantee each record is unique.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
$qb->distinct()->join('o.manyRelationship');
$i = $qb->iterator;
echo 'Profit!';
```